# Avoid escape character in Migrating the data from SQL Database to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

We are migrating the data from SQL to cosmos and after migrating the data we are seeing the data with escape characters, but it is breaking serlization  when we try to read the data from cosmosdb

`"ContactNumbers":"[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Type\":\"Phone\",}]"`

Expected : `"ContactNumbers":"[{"Id":"1","Type":"Phone",}]"`

Comment: Please edit your question to show details about how you migrated your data. As written, it's unclear what approach you took (which might explain the escape characters).

Comment: Its probably because you write you data as string instead of an object

Comment: @KrishnaRaju, here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307392/how-to-avoid-escape-character-in-migrating-the-data-from-sqldatabase-to-cosmos-d ) is a similar ask, let me know if it helps.