# Data migration from Oracle and transformation from XML to JSon

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

Can Azure Data Factory transform a string from Oracle (an xml) to a JSon Object  to save in a collection in Cosmos as a Object?
I've tried, but I only get a string (json object) as a simple attribute in Cosmos DB.

Comment: Hi,Pedro.How did you configure the adf source and sink.How does the string attribute looks like in cosmos db?Please share it, thank you?

Comment: Hi,any progress ?

Comment: I'm just started to work.
I'm going to report. Thank you.

Comment: @JayGong. Ok. My previous coworker define a atribute val_documento (String) in Cosmos, so in the mapping, adf just shows a mapping between two string attributes. I´m going to try with the DB Trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, azure data factory can transfer data, but will not help you do some serialization steps. So, you data stored in cosmos db maybe like `"info": "{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"AA\",\"Address\":\"HQ - Main Line\"}"`.

To handle with this solution,  I suggest you using [Azure Function Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function). Please refer to my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ProcessJson
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [FunctionName("DocumentUpdates")]
        public static void Run(
        [CosmosDBTrigger(databaseName:"db",collectionName: "item", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]
        IReadOnlyList<Document> documents,
        TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Verbose("Start.........");
            String endpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
            String authorizationKey = "***";
            String databaseId = "db";
            String collectionId = "import";

            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);

            for (int i = 0; i < documents.Count; i++)
            {
                Document doc = documents[i];
                String info = doc.GetPropertyValue<String>("info");
                JObject o = JObject.Parse(info);

                doc.SetPropertyValue("info", o);

                client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, doc.Id), doc);

                log.Verbose("Update document Id " + doc.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition,you could refer to my previous case:[Azure Cosmos DB SQL - how to unescape inner json property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272509/azure-cosmos-db-sql-how-to-unescape-inner-json-property/50364301#50364301)

Hope it helps you.